Syncing a local object to its stored copy in Firebase Realtime Database
I have a simple Android application in which I am using Firebase Realtime Database to store the details of the signed-in User.
Here is the User object that I am storing in the database:
public class User {

    private UserType userType;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String fullName;
    private String email;

    // addresses are stored as HOSTEL.ROOMNUMBER format
    private String hostelAddress;

    public User(UserType userType, String phoneNumber, String fullName, String email, String hostelAddress) {
        this.userType = userType;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.email = email;
        this.hostelAddress = hostelAddress;
    }


    // required for realtime Database
    public User() {
    }

    // getters and setters for all fields...
}

Every time A user signs in successfully (verified by Firebase Auth), I create a User object and store it as a value against the UID of the user as a key in the database. Everything up to this part works as expected.
Here is what that looks like:
{
  "users": {
    "<UID>": {
      "email": "<email>",
      "fullName": "<full name>",
      "hostelAddress": "<address>",
      "phoneNumber": "<number>",
      "userType": "CUSTOMER"
    }
  }
}

Now, I want to have a User Object, stored locally, that is synced with the User object stored in the database that corresponds to the currently signed user.
I want to access this User Object in different activities of my app.
For this I have made a separate class to interact with the database:
abstract public class FirebaseUtil {

    public static FirebaseDatabase database;

    public static User currentUserObject;

    public static String getCurrentUserID()
    {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
    }

    public static DatabaseReference getCurrentUserReference()
    {
        return database.getReference("users").child(getCurrentUserID());
    }

    static
    {

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        fetchCurrentUser();

    }
     
    public static void fetchCurrentUser()
    {
        if (getCurrentUserID()==null)
        {
            return;
        }
        getCurrentUserReference().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                currentUserObject = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
   
   
    // Store user inside database, with the key as its UID.
    public static void storeUser(User user, String UID)
    {
        database.getReference("users").child(UID).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                fetchCurrentUser();
            }
        });
    }
}

The problem is that this approach does not work, whenever I try to use the currentUserObject in another class in the app, it's always null, even though the getCurrentUserID() method successfully returns the logged-in User UID.
I haven't tried many things since I have no idea at all why this could not be working.
I will appreciate any push in the right direction.
And if there is a better, more reliable way to achieve this task, please let me know.

The problem is (most likely) not where you access the currentUserObject, but when you access it. Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, so you can only reliably access currentUserObject after fetchCurrentUser has completed once. ---  In addition: stop ignoring potential errors. Your onCancelled should at a minimum be public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }.

As @FrankvanPuffelen already mentioned in his comment, the issue is most likely related to the way Firebase loads the data, which is asynchronous. What I recommend is, instead of accessing fetchCurrentUser() method in each activity of your app, simply create a single call to the Realtime Database when your app starts, wait for the operation of reading the data to complete, add the user object to an Intent and navigate forward to another activity.
And yes, never ignore potential errors. So always check the error message inside the onCancelled() method by throwing the error:
throw databaseError.toException();

Or by logging the error message:
Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage());


Hey Tayyab. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Hey Alex. I see, that indeed does get the job done, thank you for your recommendation! However, even with this approach I ran into some problems. I believe this approach would work perfectly, had the User object stored in the database been constant and never changing. But if the fields of the User are subject to change, I need a way to update the Views in the different Activities accordingly, and so far I found the best way to do that is to add a listener to the Database Reference of the user in each Activity separately. If there exists a better workaround for that, I would love to hear it!

Your solution should work as long as you wait until the operation of reading the data is complete.
